# Android SQLite Database IO Error

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a strange problem when accessing android sqlite datbase. I have a line of code that opens supposed to open the database file but it displays a null pointer exception as an IOException.

```
SQLiteDatabase myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("PasswordManager", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

This isn't in an activity class this is just in a standard java class. I know the datbase exists as I am using the same line in other parts of the code, the only difference, everywhere else is inside a class that extends an activity.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a Context reference from the calling Activity to that Java class and use it to connect to your database.

Comment: To expand on Haphazard's answer. openOrCreateDatabase() is a method of the Context class. You can't call it with "this" unless you are doing it from an Activity (Context) class. Pass your Context to your other class and call openOrCreateDatabase() with it.